# Powershell pipe variable inside string

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I use

> for ($i = 0; $i -le 3; $i++) {
>   Get-ChildItem -path
>   $somepath|Copy-Item -Destination "c:\somefolder\$i-${$_.Name}"  
> }

But the destination path never translated from variables to right letters. There what I mean:
assume $i = 2 and $_.name = file.exe

> "c:\somefolder\$i-${$*.Name}"  going to c:\somefolder\2-" 
>
>   "c:\somefolder\$i-$($*.Name)"  going to c:\somefolder\2-" 
>   "c:\somefolder\${$*.Name}$i"  going to c:\somefolder\2-" 
>
>   "c:\somefolder\${$*.Name}"  going to c:\somefolder\2-" 
>  but
>   "c:\somefolder\${$_.Name}"  going to c:\somefolder\file.exe"

What am I doing wrong? How can I combine two variables together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `$_` in a string like that but you can inside a scriptblock if the scriptblock is used as the argument for a parameter that accepts pipeline input e.g.:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le 3; $i++) {
    Get-ChildItem $somepath | Copy-Item -Destination {"c:\somefolder\$i-$($_.Name)"} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But can you explain why that behaviour occur?

Comment: The `$_` is typically only available within a scriptblock inside the pipeline like `| Foreach {<$_ injected here>}` or `| Where {<$_ injected here>}`.  If a parameter is configured for pipeline binding (you can see this in the help on Copy-Item Destination parameter) then PowerShell allows you to use a scriptblock to determine the value for that parameter.  The bonus is that PowerShell will inject `$_` into that scriptblock so you can reference it there.  See item 8 & 9 in this free ebook https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=5A8D2641E0963A97&resid=5A8D2641E0963A97%216929&app=WordPdf&wdo=1